# How to insert checkbox table without refreshing the page LARAVEL PHP SQL?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, laravel

I am creating the table so one (let's say teacher) can check the attendance by selecting checkbox element( **'yes' or 'no'**).And the page should not be refreshed, there must stay the checkbox( 'yes' or 'no', one of them in box empty or tick ) So i wrote the code (logically) but it's **not working**. Could you guys help me how to solve the problem
**thank You in Advance**

Here is my **visit.blade.php**

```
>@extends('header')
>@section('content')
>  ...
> <div>
>   ...
>  <tbody class="compact ">
>                  @forelse ($group->students as $key => $student)
>                      <tr class="center aligned">
>                          <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
>                          <td class="left aligned">{{ $student->fio }}</td>
>                          @for($k = 1; $k<=$group->number_of_lessons; $k++)
>                              <td>
>                                  @if($student->has)
>                                      <div class="ui checkbox visit"><input type="checkbox" name="example" data-group-id="{{
> $group->id }}" data-student-id="{{ $student->id }}"
> data-lesson-id="{{$lesson->id}}">
>                                      </div>
>                                  @else
>                                      <div class="ui checkbox visit"><input type="checkbox" name="example" data-group-id="{{
> $group->id }}" data-student-id="{{ $student->id }}"
> data-lesson-id="{{$lesson->id}}">
>                                      </div>
>                                  @endif
> 
> 
>                              </td>
>                          @endfor
>                      </tr>
>                  @empty
>                      <tr class="center aligned">
>                          <td></td>
>                      </tr>
>                  @endforelse
>                  </tbody>
>     </div>
> @endsection
```

here is my **app.js**

```
> $('.button.add.lesson.attandence').click(function(){
>         var lesson_id = $(this).data('lesson-id');
>         var student_id = $(this).data('student-id');
>         var group_id = $(this).data('group-id');
>         var $addButton =($this);
>         $.ajax({
>             url:laroute.route('group.visits',{id:group_id}),
>             data:'student-id=' + student_id,
>             data:'lesson-id=' + lesson_id,
>             success:function(){
>                 $addButton.parent().parent().add();
>                 alertify.success('Attendance checked');
>             }
>         });
> 
>     });
```

here is my **Controller.php**

```
>   public function visits($id){
>         $group = Group::findOrFail($id);
>         foreach(Student::all() as $student) {
>             $data['students'][$student->id] = $student->fio;
>         }
>           return view('groups.visit', compact('group', 'data'));
> 
>     }
```

Here IS my **Routes.php**

```
Route::get('group/{id}/visits', ['as' => 'group.visits', 'uses' => 'GroupController@visits']);
Route::post('group/{id}/visits', ['as' => 'group.visits', 'uses' => 'GroupController@visits']);
```

Here is link to tableview **TABLE IMAGE**
https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/fr/cp0/e15/q65/16992175_779940032172228_6157498598844322627_o.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&oh=5d746dd6dd90e12ed5e379b9ad02f0b4&oe=5935D05C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the qustion over a month ago. Tried It myself, finally i managed to do this. So I am posting the answer. Maybe someone will need this in the future.
I had visits table. So I added some more rows into Controller.php

```
> public function addStudent($id, Request $request){
>        $group = Group::findOrFail($id);
>         $group->students()->sync([$request->student_id],$detaching = false);
>             $lessons = Lesson::where('group_id', $id)->get();
> 
>             foreach ($lessons as $k => $lesson) {
>                 $visit = new Visit();
>                 $visit->group_id = $id;
>                 $visit->lesson_id = $lesson->id;
>                 $visit->student_id = $request->student_id;
>                 $visit->has = false;
>                 $visit->save();
>             } 
> 
>         return back();
>     }
```

Then I removed old `@if` and `@andif` in **visit.blade.php** then I added this instead

```
> @foreach($student->visits as $k => $visit)
>                              <td>
>                                  <div class="ui {{ $visit->has ? 'checked':'' }} checkbox visit">
>                                      <input type="checkbox" data-group-id="{{ $group->id }}" data-visit-id="{{ $visit->id }}" {{
> $visit->has ? 'checked':'' }}>
>                                  </div>
>                              </td>
>                          @endforeach
```

And I lastly I wrote this scripts on **app.js**

```
> $('.checkbox.visit').checkbox({
>         onChange: function() {
>             var group_id = $(this).data('group-id');
>             var visit_id = $(this).data('visit-id');
>             var has = ($(this).parent().checkbox('is checked') ? 1:0);
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: laroute.route('group.visits', { id : group_id }),
>                 data:
>                     'visit_id=' + visit_id+
>                     '&has=' + has,
>                 success: function(result) {
>                     if(result.success) {
>                         alertify.success(result.success);
>                     }
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     });
```

I DID IT ;)